# "Numeric" is to numbers as X is to dates. What is X?

Tags: single-word-requests

"Numeric" is to numbers as X is to dates.

What is X?

Comment: Probly you're looking for _calendric_. But maybe not; there are technical uses of _calendric_ and _non-calendric_ that might interfere, as Fillmore points out in his deixis [lecture on _Time_](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/3-Time.pdf).

Comment: "Frustrated sex" is the first thing that comes to my mind.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you can use diurnal or calendrical.

Comment: _Calendric_ and _calendrical_ work in my context.